# How to get id with mongoose?

Tags: html, mongoose, ejs

So i'm following this youtube tutorial to learn the basics of mongodb and mangoose, I've managed to setup everything until I have to display an id. I've tried following the video but "undefined" appears instead of the actual id. I've tried printing in console.log but the id only prints when i use: console.log(article._id); and not console.log(article.id);

Any ideas for fixing this? Below is my code.

Here is my articles.js file :

```
const express = require('express');
const Article = require('./../models/article')
const router =  express.Router();

router.get('/new', (req, res) => {
  res.render('articles/new', { article: new Article() })
});

router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.params.id);
});

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  let article = new Article({
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
    markdown: req.body.markdown
  });   
  try {
    console.log("Try Step 1");
    console.log(article._id);
    article = article.save()
    console.log("Try Step 2");
    res.redirect(`/articles/${article.id}`);
    console.log("Try Step 3");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Error");
    res.render('articles/new', { article: article });
  }
});

module.exports = router
```

Here is my article.js file which creates the schema for article:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const articleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String
  },
  markdown: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date, 
    default: Date.now
  }
}); 

module.exports = mongoose.model('Article', articleSchema);
```

I can add any info if needed. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

By default **mongoose** adds an **_id** property to the schema. So, when you insert a new document, **mongoose** automatically adds the **_id** of [Object Type](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/objectid) to the document.

Coming to **MongoDB**, Unfortunately, **_id** property is immutable, you can't rename the **_id** property.
Refer this for know more about behavior of **_id** - [link](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents/)

**_id** property can be overwritten i.e. you can change the type of **_id** from Object Type to your own type. But, then you manually have to add value to **_id** property.

For Example

```
const schema = new Schema({_id: Number});
const model = new Model('Test', schema);

// Create new document
const doc = new Model();
await doc.save(); // Throws "document must have an _id before saving"

// Add id to document
doc._id = 1;
await doc.save(); // works
```

Please refer this link for know more about Mongoose Ids - [link](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id)

Comment: I see but how would i use the req.params.id because adding an "_" on lines, 7, 8 or 21 doesnt seem to change the fact that undefined appears so all i can do for now is print out the id in the console. ex. new ObjectId("62c82a07cf72bb9ef74ce8a2")